# GPIO Library in Windows Visual Studio 2012 (C#)

Tags: windows-iot, c#

I am developing an application in Visual Studio 2012 (C#) + Raspberry Pi 3 and I have some problems in accessing the GPIO of Raspberry Pi 3. Does anyone recommend any library that access GPIO for Windows? In Linux, I use WiringPi, but I have not succeeded using it in Windows.

Comment: Thks Joan, I will.